# Python 2.7.6 while, and If

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, methods, python-3.3

I have a simple python script that has an objective of printing an extra line when a particular name is typed in. This works in 3.3.4, however when I tried to run it in 2.7.6 the extra line wasn't printed when the name was entered in. I am guessing there is something I over looked in the changelog between both python versions. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
while True:
    name =raw_input('Piggy: What is your name?\n').strip()
    if len(name.split()) == 1:
        name = name.title()
        break
    else:
        print("Ahhhj Make it shorter or actually enter a name. If you have a name like 'Mary Joe', please separate it by using a '-'")
if name ==('dawson'):
    print('Hey Developer.')
```

Comment: `raw_input` is not in Py 3.x, so it wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @thefourtheye I am writing this in python 2.7.6, I had to downgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call `name.title()` and replace `name`, and then you compare it with a lowercase string. It will never match.

Comment: So it would work if I capitalized the name in the second if statement because name is being stored as a title?

Comment: Or you could compare `name.lower()`.